# How to silence -Wunreachable-code-return (GCC/Clang)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

When using a function that has the noreturn attribute?

The following code gives a warning at the last line.

```
extern void main_loop(void) __attribute__ ((noreturn));

int my_event_loop(void)
{
    main_loop();
    return MY_SUCCESS_ENUM;   /* <- '-Wunreachable-code-return' */
}
```

Note the return value is needed so the function fits an interface and can be assigned to a callback.

---

- Removing it may give problems for compilers that don't support `noreturn` attribute.
- Using the `#pragma GCC diagnostic push/pop` will work but is quite verbose.

Is there a better way to quiet the warning at the last return?

Comment: You can refactor this code quite easily: `if (ok) main_loop(); return -1;`

Comment: For some reason I am not able to reproduce the warning even with `-Wall -Wextra`. I can't do it even if I replace `main_loop()` with `exit(-1)`. Can you specify your compiler version and any other flags you passed?

Comment: @squeamish-ossifrage - your right, in fact this wasn't relevant to include in the question, edited.

Comment: Why `#pragma GCC diagnostic` is not ok? You could also use `_Pragma` and define your macro for that

Comment: @basile-starynkevitch - mainly to avoid littering the code with pragma's for each compiler that has some pedantic behavior (MSVC/ICC/CLANG/GCC)... it can get a bit messy. If there are no alternatives it's not so bad but I might just leave the warning in and not worry about it.